# Sentense-structure: Meaning of "Had I been"

Tags: subjunctives

I've seen this structure on a Quora post

> *Had I been* a Muslim man, I would've been able to have sex plenty, and society wouldn't know at all because I would've had no hymen, but as a Muslim woman, my sins were easier to track.

What does that "Had I + Past participle verb" mean?

This is the post I'm referring to:

https://www.quora.com/Why-did-you-stop-wearing-a-hijab/answer/Salma-Medina-1?ch=10&share=fc0fe9cf&srid=HF4KJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Had I been a muslimman, I would  have been able to have  sex plenty**

This is equal to the unfulfulled conditional (conditional 3)

> **If I had been a muslim man , I would have been able to have sex plenty**

The only difference between the two structutes is :

In the first sentence there is an inversion of the verb **had**  and  **if**     is omitted..

The sentence means **I was not a muslim man ( but I was a muslim woman),  so  I was not able to have sex plenty**

In the link you provided, The woman thinks that as a muslim woman she did not have the freedom of a muslim man.
She was not able to do what she wanted to do as she was a muslim woman

You can  use similar structures in  your  writing.

**Had I been a professor, I would have taught English lessons**

**Had I been a doctor, I would have treated the patients**

Comment: *Had I been X, I would've been able to do Y* implies that someone **wasn't** (i.e. in the past) X, but that if they'd been, they would have been able, at that time, to do Y. There is such a thing as a doubly remote conditional, where the unreal situation isn't situated in the past, but this isn't one. Second of all, this construction isn't as well-represented in speech – it's somewhat formal / literary.